# Dynamics Ax outbound xml transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, ax

This xml generates from Dynamics Ax which need transformation (XSLT): Need to create an XSLT in order to get intended outbound xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId>{3BCFB0D6-EAB4-430E-9921-E365F189046D}</MessageId>
    <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/LedgerExchangeRateService/read</Action>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
      <LedgerExchangeRate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/LedgerExchangeRate">
        <SenderId>Womar</SenderId>
        <CurrencyPair class="entity">
          <FromCurrencyCode>US</FromCurrencyCode>
          <ToCurrencyCode>DKK</ToCurrencyCode>
          <ExchangeRateType>Default</ExchangeRateType>
          <ExchangeRateDisplayFactor>Hundred</ExchangeRateDisplayFactor>
          <ExchangeRate class="entity">
            <ExchangeRate>500.000000000000</ExchangeRate>
            <ValidFrom>2013-05-17</ValidFrom>
          </ExchangeRate>
          <RateType class="entity">
            <Name>Default</Name>
          </RateType>
        </CurrencyPair>
      </LedgerExchangeRate>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

After transformation, the file will be as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<exchangeRateImport action="create" xmlns="http://schemas.v.com/2005/ImosOps" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <baseCurrency>US</baseCurrency>
  <currency>EU</currency>
  <rate>55.00000000</rate>
  <effectiveDate>2013-05-17</effectiveDate>
</exchangeRateImport>
```

I have created an XLRT as follows which results differently. Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:axEnv="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
                xmlns:axExchRate="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/LedgerExchangeRate">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <exchangeRateImport imosMsg:action="update" xmlns:imosMsg="http://schemas.veson.com/2005/ImosMsg" xmlns="http://schemas.veson.com/2005/ImosOps" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <baseCurrency>
        <xsl:value-of select="axEnv:Envelope/axEnv:body/axEnv:MessageParts/axExchRate:LedgerExchangeRate/axExchRate:CurrencyPair/axExchRate:FromCurrencyCode"/>
      </baseCurrency>
      <currency/>
      <rate/>
      <effectiveDate/>
    </exchangeRateImport>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<exchangeRateImport imosMsg:action="update" xmlns="http://schemas.veson.com/2005/ImosOps" xmlns:imosMsg="http://schemas.veson.com/2005/ImosMsg" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:axEnv="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" xmlns:axExchRate="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/LedgerExchangeRate"><baseCurrency></baseCurrency><currency /><rate /><effectiveDate /></exchangeRateImport>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason your transform isn't working is that the `axEnv:body` element isn't being found because it has a capital `B` in the source XML.

I don't fully understand what it is you need, as the XML you say you require barely corresponds to the source data at all. However here is my best guess. I hope it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:axEnv="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
    xmlns:axExchRate="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/LedgerExchangeRate"
    exclude-result-prefixes="axEnv axExchRate">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="axEnv:Envelope/axEnv:Body/axEnv:MessageParts/axExchRate:LedgerExchangeRate/axExchRate:CurrencyPair"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="axExchRate:CurrencyPair">

    <exchangeRateImport
        imosMsg:action="update"
        xmlns="http://schemas.veson.com/2005/ImosOps"
        xmlns:imosMsg="http://schemas.veson.com/2005/ImosMsg"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <baseCurrency>
        <xsl:value-of select="axExchRate:FromCurrencyCode"/>
      </baseCurrency>
      <currency>
        <xsl:value-of select="axExchRate:ToCurrencyCode"/>
      </currency>
      <rate>
        <xsl:value-of select="axExchRate:ExchangeRate/axExchRate:ExchangeRate"/>
      </rate>
      <effectiveDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="axExchRate:ExchangeRate/axExchRate:ValidFrom"/>
      </effectiveDate>
    </exchangeRateImport>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<exchangeRateImport
    xmlns="http://schemas.veson.com/2005/ImosOps" 
    xmlns:imosMsg="http://schemas.veson.com/2005/ImosMsg" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    imosMsg:action="update">

  <baseCurrency>US</baseCurrency>
  <currency>DKK</currency>
  <rate>500.000000000000</rate>
  <effectiveDate>2013-05-17</effectiveDate>
</exchangeRateImport>
```

Comment: Hi Borodin, First of all many thanks for ur contribution. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Borodin,many thanks for ur contribution. Really appreciate it. Basically, the source system "dynamics ax" generate an xml file based on its own xsd where as the destination xml has a dfrnt format,but the information set are fixed. So, in source system we have an option to upload a xsl file which will do the transformation from source xml. We call this AIF (Application Integration Framework). I am just started learning xslt. May I know if it possible to remove the source namespaces as xmlns:axEnv="http:../documents/Message" and   xmlns:axExchRate="http:..LedgerExchangeRate" from output file

Comment: @Dip: Yes, you can add a `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute to the `<xsl:stylesheet>` root element. I have altered my answer accordingly.